# Dynamic Json to CSV in java. looking for Generic code that works with any json, irrespective of any number of node in json file

Tags: java, json, csv, parsing

hi i need to convert all json elements into csv . json is dynamic file, number of field and names will change from file to file.
i tried different methods but most cases i need to mention field names in scripts to pull data into csv

JSON file

```
[
    {
        "system": "Application",
        "id": "12345",
        "version": 1,
        "event": "NEW",
        "keywords": {
            "ProductType": "ALL",
            "Business": "USA",
        },
        "product": {
            "type": "INS",
            "startDate": 20190102,
            "endDate": 20190104,
            "cash": 100000.00,
            "sub": {
                "type": "Life",
                "productId": 987,
                "maturityDate": 20260421,               
            },
            "paymentCalendar": [
                "Monthly"
            ],
            "duration": "20Y",
            "Amount": 1000.00,
            "cashFlows": [
                {
                    "startDate": 20190102,
                    "endDate": 20190104,
                    "paymentDate": 20190104,
                }
            ],
            "principalFlows": [
                {
                    "startDate": 20190102,
                    "endDate": 20190104,
                    "paymentDate": 20190102,
                    "currency": "USA",
                    "amount": 400.0
                },
                {
                    "startDate": 20190104,
                    "endDate": 20190104,
                    "paymentDate": 20190104,
                    "currency": "USA",
                    "amount": 600.0
                }
            ]
        },
        "EventDate": 20190108,
        "maturityDate": 20190104
    }
]
```

above fields are not constant, all filed will keep changing.

expected output is below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html) you can implement the functionality you require by reading the JSON and then visiting all the nodes.

1. If the node is a collection then visit all its children with the field or array index appended to the prefix

   - Note that arrays and objects need to be handled independently
2. If the node is a not a collection then add it to the CSV output

```
    public void jsonToCsv(String json, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
        JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().reader().readTree(json);
        CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.print(appendable);
        appendNode(root.get(0), "", printer);
    }

    private void appendNode(JsonNode node, String prefix, CSVPrinter printer) throws IOException {
        if (node.isArray()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.size(); ++i) {
                appendNode(node.get(i), String.format("%s/%d", prefix, i), printer);
            }
        } else if (node.isContainerNode()) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = node.fields();
            while (fields.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
                appendNode(field.getValue(), String.format("%s/%s", prefix, field.getKey()), printer);
            }
        } else {
            printer.printRecord(prefix.substring(1), node.asText());
        }
    }
```